# Set-builder notation for $\Bbb{Z}^n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a vector $\mathbf{i} \in \Bbb{Z}^n$ and I want to declare that $f(\mathbf{i}) = 1$ and any close neighbor  $\mathbf{x}$ of $\mathbf{i}$, either diagonal or orthogonal (e.g. in $\Bbb{Z}^2$ it will be left, right, top, bottom, top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right neighbors), gives $f(\mathbf{x}) = 1$

Is it correct notation:

$$\forall \mathbf{x} \in \{\mathbf{x} \in\Bbb{Z}^n | \mathbf{i}-1\le x \le \mathbf{i}+1\}, f(\mathbf{x}) = 1$$

I'm a bit confused with the fact I used "$\mathbf{x} \in$" twice in the expression. Also I'm not sure that it's correct to add an integer 1 to the vector $\mathbf{i}$ in "$\mathbf{i}-1\le x \le \mathbf{i}+1$" part.

Comment: No real issue with the variables; you can simply use a different one for the formula specifying the set $\{ z \in \mathbb Z^n \mid \ldots \}$

Comment: Call this set $S$; then your formula will be $\forall x (x \in S \to f(x)=1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding adding scalars and vectors: you're right, you can't do that. What you need is a distance function (norm) on $\mathbb Z^n$. I think the specific one you want is
$$ \|\cdot\| : \mathbb Z^n \to [0,\infty) , \quad \|\mathbf v\| := \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|$$ Then your set is
$$ B := \{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb Z^n \mid \|\mathbf x - \mathbf i \| \le 1 \}$$
Now that I've given this set a name, you can go ahead and write what you want as
$$ \forall \mathbf  x \in B , \ f(\mathbf x) = 1$$
If you want to show that it depends on $\mathbf i$, you might want to write $B(\mathbf i)$.  If you want to replace the number 1 with other numbers $r>0$, i.e. $|\mathbf x - \mathbf i | \le r$ you might want to write $B(\mathbf i, r)$. FYI if this was $\mathbb R^n$ instead of $\mathbb Z^n$, this would be the closed ball of radius $r$ around $\mathbf i$. (This norm is usually called the 1-norm, or the $\ell^1$ norm. [Here's the wikipedia page on balls.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29#In_normed_vector_spaces). You might  As the comment by Ennar indicates, this is a lattice in $\mathbb R^n$. It inherits the subspace metric from the vector space $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: $\mathbb Z^n$ isn't a vector space naturally since field doesn't act on it. It only has natural action of $\mathbb Z$, so it is a $\mathbb Z$-module, which is just an abelian group. However, it is a lattice in vector space $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I think I've made a mistake by saying "no further than 1". If I use L1 norm I get (in $\Bbb{Z}^2$) only left, right, top and bottom neighbors, but I need the "diagonal" ones too. Is there way to rewrite "$\mathbf{i}-1\le x \le \mathbf{i}+1$" condtition?

Comment: @True do day, use $\infty$-norm instead: $||v||_\infty = \max_j\{|v_j|\}$.

Comment: @Ennar that's amazing that it slipped by me, thank you very much for the correction. I'll fix it now